# Why are my renders of glass turning out strange?

Tags: rendering, glass

When i render glass it keeps showing up black, i have turn on and off ambient lighting (both kinds) and also have added a sun lamp but it still shows up black. Any solutions? Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

[image]

Comment: id be happy to tell you my settings if needed. Also i have transparent checked and tried it on/off it didnt work

Comment: ok here is the link https://i.imgur.com/NgNYjdD.png the white/black is the glass

Comment: @cegaton heres the link https://i.imgur.com/NgNYjdD.png

Comment: we still do not know much about your scene. How did you set up the glass material? How do we know that what is black is not the reflection of some black background? How many bounces are you using in the light path section? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post to add more information https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your file for others to inspect.

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal or Cycles engine?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem for a while; what I eventually figured out was going on was that I needed to increase the number of transmission samples in the Light Paths tab in the Render panel.  This dictates how many transparent surfaces the light can pass through.  For example, if you are rendering something through a window, it should show through.  But if you then add another window in front of that one, and then another one, and so on, you'll reach a point where the glass suddenly starts showing up black.  That's because the transmission samples aren't high enough, so the light isn't able to travel through so many transparent surfaces.  The solution is to just increase the number of transmission samples.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It didnt work but thanks :/ :)