# Why are some of my transparent objects rendering as black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm trying to render an image on Cycles, I have a group of grass meshes with a transparent material, but when I rendered the image they looked like this, I tried using a Transparent BDSF node with a mixed Shader node but it didn't work, as you can see, some straws seem to be transparent, but the rest are not (all straws use the same material), my guess is that the rays stop at some point because of the plane mesh, any solution?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black artifacts when looking through many transparent objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/black-artifacts-when-looking-through-many-transparent-objects) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90409/why-are-my-renders-of-glass-turning-out-strange/90416#90416

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42023/transparent-textured-planes-produce-black-artifacts